# queue_draw_area with a specific handler?

Tags: python, gtk, cairo, gdk

I'm using Cairo with a `gi.repository.Gtk.DrawingArea`, and I need to handle two different kinds of events:

- Update a summary line (`draw_summary()`)
- Draw a new dot (`draw_dot()`

Ideally I'd invalidate only a small area (like a vertical strip of my drawing area) when I need to do a `draw_dot()`, and I'd invalidate a different area when I want to `draw_dummary()`. I could redraw the entire region every time, but this will get expensive and I'd rather only update the places that need it.

As far as I can determine, my only available triggering mechanism is to call:

```
      plot.queue_draw_area
```

-- but this call in turn is connected to the `draw` event via:

```
      self.plot_area.connect("draw", self.handle_draw)
```

... which means I have no way to queue a `draw_dot` separately from a `draw_summary` call. When I call `queue_draw_area`, all I can do is invoke my one handler. Is there a standard pattern for breaking down a drawing operation into separate functions that can be queued independently?

Comment: There are two things you can do: you can either block the individual connections with `g_signal_handler_block()` and `g_signal_handler_unblock()` (or their Python equivalents), or get the clipping region of the cairo context in your draw handlers and do nothing if you wouldn't be drawing there anyway (see the GtkWidget::draw documentation for details).

Comment: Thanks -- that's helpful, but it still means that my drawing callback needs to effectively do all the logic of drawing everything to figure out (rather than being told) what operations to take. I'm looking to flip this model on its head (since my code that's calling invalidate actually knows what needs to happen).

Answer (score 1):

Uhm. How does your drawing actually work? I mean, GTK could also call your callback for other reasons than your internal redraws. So you drawing callback has to be able to handle a full redraw anyway.

For your optimization: You can get the cairo context's clip context to figure out in which part actually needs to be redrawn. The function in C is `cairo_clip_extents` to get a bounding rectangle and `cairo_copy_clip_rectangle_list' to get a list of all the individual rectangles that are part of the clip.